# accordian menu slideToggle not sliding up

Tags: jquery

I have created a super simple accordian menu. But I have run into a problem. The slideToggle is not working. I am not sure if it is because I am hiding the element on click and that is creating the confusion. If anyone could take a look, I woiuld greatly appreciate it. But I really am trying yo keep the code as SIMPLE as possible. Thanks!!

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/liveandream/Yd2Pd/

Comment: It would be best for future readers if the actual code was part of the question since the jsFiddle link will go dead some day.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Updated the fiddle, works now: http://jsfiddle.net/Yd2Pd/7/

You didn't need the extra line of

```
$(".drop").slideUp();
```

This line does the job just fine without the above line.

```
$(".drop", this).slideToggle("slow");
```

Comment: sorry this does not work for me, because I need to have the other ones slideup. In other words only one drop down menu should show at a time. I am sorry for the misunderstanding. But if you look in my original jsfiddle, you will see that if a drop down is visible and you click on a different one, the visible one will slide up. Thanks!